# Android Studio reports "android sdk is parsed incorrectly"

Tags: java, android, android-studio

I just migrated an android project from eclipse to android studio but when I try to compile it I get the error "android sdk is parsed incorrectly".

any help?

Comment: which version are u using

Comment: AI-130.677228 (I think)

Answer (score 0):

Try configuring Android Studio to point to your sdk installation.